# Image blurry when box-sizing: border-box applied

Tags: css

Can anyone tell me why the top image is blurry?

http://blog.distance.mun.ca/technologyresources/why-blurry/

The first has width and height set, and the second one has that removed. That's the only difference. I suspect the box-sizing property is throwing it off somehow. But I can't figure out why!

Advice welcome!

Thanks

ps: A good run-down on border-box: http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's blurry because you are setting the size of the image to something not its native size and the browser has to resample the pixels in the image in order fit.

If you look at the page you provided the top image has a size of 416x150 while the bottom 418x151.

If you set the height and width equal to the actual dimensions of the image you shouldn't have that problem.

Comment: What the! Why is this happening? Both images have this value in the inspector: http://cl.ly/image/1v3E03122c1Q Why would it be resizing them?